# Colors overwriting texture mapping in opengl es

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am using opengl es with android. I have have three objects on the screen, two of which I am not using a texture map, just colors, and one of which I am. When I comment out the code that draws the two color objects, the texture maps onto my other object fine, but when the two color objects are present, the texture does not map onto my object and I just get a white square. Is there a call I need to make to opengl after I draw the color objects so that the texture will render on the other object?

Comment: It can be a million things wrong(ok maybe not that much) .Without some code its hard to find the problem even for a veteran opengl dev . Did you checked for glEnable/Disable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) mistakes?

Comment: @SteveL Well on the on surface created method I enable GL_TEXTURE_2D, but should I be enabling/disabling as appropriate in the ondrawframe method?

Comment: @SteveL that was it thanks for the nod in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you draw the two color objects i guess you are calling `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` ,if so you need to call `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` before you draw the object with the texture.

So your code should be something like that:

```
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
drawColorObject1();
drawColorObject1();

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
drawTextureObject();
```